# I need some examples of sending parameters in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

How do I send parameters in smalltalk:

- Pass-by-Value
- Pass-by-Result
- Pass-by-Value-result
- Pass-by-References
- Pass-by-Name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAK, **Smallscript** Smalltalk uses pass-by-value as default unless you use the & sign for pass by reference just like C++, there is more information on this [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg00955.html).

**But** traditionally Smalltalk uses pass by reference as mentioned [here](http://classicalprogrammer.wikidot.com/variables) and [here](http://www.deadman.ca/articles/rome.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can safely assume that all parameters in smalltalk are passed by reference.

There's only one exception for immediate object (smallintegers) which are passed by value,
but its an implementation detail (different implementations could have different kinds of immediate object classes).